# How to debug typescript code, which is bundled using webpack in vscode/vs2015

Tags: typescript, gulp, webpack, visual-studio-code

Here is my workflow.

I have moduled typescript code. Imports like the following: `import { Logger } from './../data/logger';`

Then I bundle it using webpack (precisely - webpack-stream) with ts-loader. I run webpack using gulp.

So I have the following workflow:
gulp --> webpack (ts-loader) --> bundled *.js with source-maps. I also use the [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) to run simple server and auto update the page.

I can debug this code from the browser, but I can't from vscode (using [Chrome Debugging for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code), or even from vs2015.

What could cause the problem ?

Comment: DId you ever get it working? If so, could you add an answer explaining how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Typescript is a bit different than debugging c# code. You need to debug from **SourceMap**.

To learn more about SourceMap, [check this link](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2012-10-03-typescript-source-maps.html).

Source level debugging is available in TypeScript since version [0.8.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1/)

And if you want to read more about using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015, Telerik has a great post about it on its [developer blog](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/typescript-with-visual-studio-2015/).